# Do AWS Spectrum really need = in s3 location to understand it as hive format?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hive, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I run some test with `spectrum`.

I created two `AWS Glue crawler`.

The first one called `hive-tst` which scans:

```
s3://hive-test/type='a'/year='2021'/month='01'
s3://hive-test/type='b'/year='2021'/month='01'
s3://hive-test/type='c'/year='2021'/month='01'
s3://hive-test/type='d'/year='2021'/month='01'
s3://hive-test/type='e'/year='2021'/month='01'
```

The second one scans:

```
s3://non-hive-test/a/2021/01
s3://non-hive-test/b/2021/01
s3://non-hive-test/c/2021/01
s3://non-hive-test/d/2021/01
s3://non-hive-test/e/2021/01
```

Both has two files in each bucket partition, both files are `parquet` files with 50mb.

Then I run a test of querying first partition of each `spectrum` table:

```
select distinct event from test.hive_tst;
```

It took 8s 272

```
select distinct partition_0 from test.nonhive_tst;
```

It took 8s 66ms

So it doesn't seem that adding the `=` improves performance.
Also checked that both tables have `Hive` format in partitions.

```
select *
from svv_external_partitions
where schemaname='test'
and tablename='hive_tst';
```

| values | location | input_format | output_format | serialization_lib |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ["a","2021","01"] | s3://hive-test/event=a/year=2021/month=01/ | org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat | org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat | org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe |

```
select *
from svv_external_partitions
where schemaname='test'
and tablename='nonhive_tst';
```

| values | location | input_format | output_format | serialization_lib |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ["a","2021","01"] | s3://hive-test/a/2021/01/ | org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat | org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat | org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe |

Maybe the data volume in the folders is not enough to test it, but everything, execution-times, and partitions format using `svv_external_partitions` seem the same.

Then the question is:

Do AWS Spectrum really need = in s3 location to understand it as hive format?

Comment: Both buckets have `=` between the partition names and its values. Where is there supposed to be a differences? I would not expect the `'` around the values by the way.

Comment: @luk2302 error typing, already fixed

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after a lot of search and reading I get into a conclusion:
Both `S3` buckets have partitions, and as we use `AWS Glue`, all partitions are automatically added.

The only difference is that prefix such as `year=2020` corresponds to hive naming convention, so `AWS Glue` knows how to handle that when add the partitions, and then partitions have a pretty name such as `year` instead of `partition_x`.

Then, answering: **Do AWS Spectrum really need = in s3 location to understand it as hive format?**

No, you don't need it to understant as `hive` format, but to understand it with `Hive` naming convention

**Sources**

1. My own test above
2. [AWS Glue partitioned data post](https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/big-data/work-with-partitioned-data-in-aws-glue/)
3. [Hive naming convention on S3](https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/big-data/amazon-kinesis-data-firehose-custom-prefixes-for-amazon-s3-objects/)